Эффективная проверка равенства блоков памяти в C/C++
Меня интересует максимально эффективная проверка равенства блоков памяти.
В настоящее время я использую memcmp(...) == 0 для определения равенства. Хотя это работает, memcmp предназначен не только для проверки равенства, но и для определения порядка двух участков памяти (больше, меньше или равно). Эта дополнительная функциональность может вызывать ненужные накладные расходы.
Задача.
Требуется максимально эффективно проверить равенство или неравенство двух участков памяти.
Проблема.
Факт того, что memcmp предоставляет информацию о порядке, означает, что он может быть менее эффективным, чем функция, специально предназначенная только для проверки равенства.
Дополнительные накладные расходы в memcmp связаны с необходимостью определения точного порядка блоков, если они не равны. Например, если memcmp возвращает ненулевой результат, это означает, что существуют два байта по какому-то индексу i в каждом блоке памяти, которые отличаются определённым образом, а все предыдущие байты равны. Для этого memcmp должен проверить равенство всех предыдущих байтов, что требует времени. В то время как функция, которая только проверяет равенство, может, например, сразу проверить последние байты и, найдя отличие, немедленно завершить проверку. Это может привести к амортизационному улучшению асимптотики по времени.
Более простыми словами: неэффективность memcmp связана с тем, что он ищет не любую разницу между блоками памяти, а САМУЮ ЛЕВУЮ разницу.
Что я пробовал.
Я написал собственные реализации для демонстрации этой идеи и провёл тесты.
#include <cstring>
#include <immintrin.h>

bool memcmp_memeq(const void* s1, const void* s2, size_t n) {
    return memcmp(s1, s2, n) == 0;
}

bool my_memeq(const void* s1, const void* s2, size_t n) {
    const static size_t simd_width = 16;

    if (n <= simd_width) {
        return memcmp(s1, s2, n) == 0;
    }

    const int8_t* end1 = (const int8_t*)s1 + n - simd_width;
    const int8_t* end2 = (const int8_t*)s2 + n - simd_width;

    const __m128i m1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)end1);
    const __m128i m2 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)end2);
    const __m128i result = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(m1, m2);

    if (_mm_movemask_epi8(result) != 0xFFFF) {
        return false;
    }

    return memcmp(s1, s2, (const int8_t*)end1 - (const int8_t*)s1) == 0;
}

bool my_memeq_256(const void* s1, const void* s2, size_t n) {
    const static size_t simd_width = 32;

    if (n <= simd_width) {
        return memcmp(s1, s2, n) == 0;
    }

    const int8_t* end1 = (const int8_t*)s1 + n - simd_width;
    const int8_t* end2 = (const int8_t*)s2 + n - simd_width;

    const __m256i m1 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)end1);
    const __m256i m2 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)end2);
    const __m256i result = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(m1, m2);

    if (static_cast<unsigned int>(_mm256_movemask_epi8(result)) != 0xFFFFFFFF) {
        return false;
    }

    return memcmp(s1, s2, (const int8_t*)end1 - (const int8_t*)s1) == 0;
}

#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include <src/util/my_memeq.h>


template <typename Func>
std::pair<std::chrono::duration<double>, bool> measure_time(
        Func func,
        const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>& test_cases,
        int iterations = 100000) {
    if (test_cases.empty()) {
        return { std::chrono::duration<double>(0), true };
    }
    volatile bool result;
    const auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
        for (const auto& test_case : test_cases) {
            result = func(test_case.first.c_str(), test_case.second.c_str(), test_case.first.size());
        }
    }
    const auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    return { (end - start) / test_cases.size() / iterations, result };
}


void run_tests(std::ostream& out, size_t len, const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>& test_cases) {

    const auto memcmp_memeq_time_result = measure_time(memcmp_memeq, test_cases);
    const auto my_memeq_time_result = measure_time(my_memeq, test_cases);
    const auto my_memeq_256_time_result = measure_time(my_memeq_256, test_cases);

    const auto memcmp_memeq_time = memcmp_memeq_time_result.first.count();
    const auto my_memeq_time = my_memeq_time_result.first.count();
    const auto my_memeq_256_time = my_memeq_256_time_result.first.count();

    const auto memcmp_memeq_result = memcmp_memeq_time_result.second;
    const auto my_memeq_result = my_memeq_time_result.second;
    const auto my_memeq_256_result = my_memeq_256_time_result.second;

    EXPECT_EQ(memcmp_memeq_result, my_memeq_result);
    EXPECT_EQ(memcmp_memeq_result, my_memeq_256_result);

    out << "RESULTS for len: " << len << " bytes\n";
    out << std::setw(19) << "memcmp_memeq time: " << std::setw(9) << std::setprecision(4) << memcmp_memeq_time << " seconds\n";
    out << std::setw(19) << "my_memeq time: " << std::setw(9) << std::setprecision(4) << my_memeq_time << " seconds\n";
    out << std::setw(19) << "my_memeq_256 time: " << std::setw(9) << std::setprecision(4) << my_memeq_256_time << " seconds\n";
    out << '\n';
}


std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>
    generate_test_cases(
        size_t len,
        bool include_equal = true,
        bool include_start = true,
        bool include_middle = true,
        bool include_end = true,
        bool include_quarters = true) {

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> test_cases;

    std::string str1 (len, 'A');
    std::string str2 (len, 'A');

    if (include_equal) {
        test_cases.emplace_back(str1, str2);
    }

    if (include_end) {
        str2[len - 1] = 'B';
        test_cases.emplace_back(str1, str2);
        str2[len - 1] = 'A';
    }

    if (include_start) {
        str2[0] = 'B';
        test_cases.emplace_back(str1, str2);
        str2[0] = 'A';
    }

    if (include_middle) {
        if (len > 2) {
            str2[len / 2] = 'B';
            test_cases.emplace_back(str1, str2);
            str2[len / 2] = 'A';
        }
    }

    if (include_quarters) {
        if (len > 4) {
            str2[len / 4] = 'B';
            test_cases.emplace_back(str1, str2);
            str2[len / 4] = 'A';

            str2[len / 4 * 3] = 'B';
            test_cases.emplace_back(str1, str2);
            str2[len / 4 * 3] = 'A';
        }
    }

    return test_cases;
}


TEST(MemcmpTest, PerformanceComparison) {

    const static size_t start_len = 4;
    const static size_t max_bytes = 131072;

    std::stringstream out;

    out << "VARIOUS STRINGS\n\n";
    for (size_t len = start_len; len <= max_bytes; len *= 2) {
        run_tests(
                out,
                len,
                generate_test_cases(
                        len,
                        true,
                        true,
                        true,
                        true,
                        true)
        );
    }

    out << "DIFFERENCE AT THE START\n\n";
    for (size_t len = start_len; len <= max_bytes; len *= 2) {
        run_tests(
                out,
                len,
                generate_test_cases(
                        len,
                        false,
                        true,
                        false,
                        false,
                        false)
        );
    }

    out << "DIFFERENCE AT THE END\n\n";
    for (size_t len = start_len; len <= max_bytes; len *= 2) {
        run_tests(
                out,
                len,
                generate_test_cases(
                        len,
                        false,
                        false,
                        false,
                        true,
                        false)
        );
    }

    out << "DIFFERENCE AT THE MIDDLE\n\n";
    for (size_t len = start_len; len <= max_bytes; len *= 2) {
        run_tests(
                out,
                len,
                generate_test_cases(
                        len,
                        false,
                        false,
                        true,
                        false,
                        false)
        );
    }

    const auto output = out.str();
//  std::cout << output;

    {{ std::ofstream out_file ("../test/my_memeq_test_results.txt");
        out_file << output;
    }}
}

Результаты тестирования:
VARIOUS STRINGS

RESULTS for len: 4 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   1.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   1.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   1.6e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 8 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   1.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   1.6e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   1.6e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 16 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   1.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   1.6e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   1.6e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 32 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   1.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   1.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   1.6e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 64 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   1.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   1.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   1.8e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 128 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   1.5e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   1.8e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   1.9e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 256 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   1.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   1.8e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   1.9e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 512 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   1.7e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   1.9e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:     2e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 1024 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   1.9e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.1e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.2e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 2048 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.5e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.5e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.6e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 4096 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   4.1e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   3.3e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   3.5e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 8192 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:     8e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:     6e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:     6e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 16384 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:  1.57e-07 seconds
    my_memeq time:  1.21e-07 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:  1.22e-07 seconds

RESULTS for len: 32768 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:  2.97e-07 seconds
    my_memeq time:  2.19e-07 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.2e-07 seconds

RESULTS for len: 65536 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:  6.34e-07 seconds
    my_memeq time:  4.25e-07 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:  4.26e-07 seconds

RESULTS for len: 131072 bytes
memcmp_memeq time: 1.429e-06 seconds
    my_memeq time:  9.97e-07 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   9.8e-07 seconds

DIFFERENCE AT THE START

RESULTS for len: 4 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.6e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 8 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.6e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 16 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.6e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 32 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.8e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.6e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 64 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.9e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 128 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.9e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 256 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.8e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.8e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 512 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.8e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.9e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 1024 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.8e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 2048 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.8e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 4096 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.9e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 8192 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.4e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.9e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 16384 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.8e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 32768 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.8e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 65536 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.8e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 131072 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.9e-08 seconds

DIFFERENCE AT THE END

RESULTS for len: 4 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.5e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.6e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 8 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.5e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.6e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 16 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.6e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 32 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.6e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 64 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.8e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 128 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.9e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 256 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.9e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 512 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:     3e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.9e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 1024 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   3.5e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.8e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 2048 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   4.2e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.9e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 4096 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   6.1e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.9e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 8192 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   9.8e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.9e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 16384 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:  1.95e-07 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.9e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 32768 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:  4.84e-07 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.9e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 65536 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:  9.42e-07 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.9e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 131072 bytes
memcmp_memeq time: 1.862e-06 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.9e-08 seconds

DIFFERENCE AT THE MIDDLE

RESULTS for len: 4 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.6e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 8 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   3.2e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   4.9e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 16 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.7e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 32 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.8e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.8e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.7e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 64 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:     3e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:     3e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 128 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.8e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:     3e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   3.2e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 256 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.8e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   3.3e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   3.1e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 512 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   3.1e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   3.2e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   3.3e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 1024 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   3.3e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   3.4e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   3.6e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 2048 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   3.7e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   3.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   3.8e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 4096 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   4.3e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   4.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   4.8e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 8192 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   5.8e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:     6e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   6.1e-08 seconds

RESULTS for len: 16384 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:  1.02e-07 seconds
    my_memeq time:  1.06e-07 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:  1.07e-07 seconds

RESULTS for len: 32768 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:  2.31e-07 seconds
    my_memeq time:  2.36e-07 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:  2.41e-07 seconds

RESULTS for len: 65536 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:  5.17e-07 seconds
    my_memeq time:   5.2e-07 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:  5.23e-07 seconds

RESULTS for len: 131072 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   9.9e-07 seconds
    my_memeq time: 1.007e-06 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:  9.78e-07 seconds

Отдельно приведу результаты для самых длинных блоков памяти:
VARIOUS STRINGS
RESULTS for len: 131072 bytes
memcmp_memeq time: 1.429e-06 seconds
    my_memeq time:  9.97e-07 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   9.8e-07 seconds

DIFFERENCE AT THE START
RESULTS for len: 131072 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   2.6e-08 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.9e-08 seconds

DIFFERENCE AT THE END
RESULTS for len: 131072 bytes
memcmp_memeq time: 1.862e-06 seconds
    my_memeq time:   2.7e-08 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:   2.9e-08 seconds

DIFFERENCE AT THE MIDDLE
RESULTS for len: 131072 bytes
memcmp_memeq time:   9.9e-07 seconds
    my_memeq time: 1.007e-06 seconds
my_memeq_256 time:  9.78e-07 seconds

Как видно, мои реализации могут дать существенный прирост производительности в отдельных случаях.
Однако можно ожидать и небольшого падения производительности для маленьких блоков памяти.
Меня интересует: есть ли уже готовое решение, специально оптимизированное для проверки равенства блоков памяти?

Мне кажется такая проверка чуть не на уровне инструкций процессора уже вшита, поэтому быстрее именно целиком блок проверять, чем ручные оптимизации делать. Разве что у вас есть какой-то инсайд какой именно байт скорее всего будет отличаться - первый или, например, последний, тогда может и выгодно будет сначала проверить эти отдельные байты, а потом уже целиком блок, если те байты оказались одинаковые.

Можно со всей уверенностью сказать что если вы ускорите работу сравнения в каких-то ситуациях, вы в той же степени замедлите сравнение в других ситуациях. В среднем ваше решение будет сравнимо с memcmp или хуже.

Ещё одно соображение: memcmp не тратит время на определение порядка байтов. Это происходит на уровне железа процессора. С точки зрения программиста операции "неравенство" и "порядок" требуют одного и того же времени.

Оптимизация включена? Для начала, надо бы добавить итераций, чтобы прогоны занимали какое-то заметное время, а не доли миллисекунд.

Я правильно понял, что ваш метод сводится к тому, что вы сначала сравниваете хвосты (16 байт в одном случае и 32 во втором), а потом, если они совпали, вызываете memcmp?  / Кстати (читать весь этот код просо лень), вы приводите результат одного прогона тестов (или это минамальное время, или среднее за несколько прогонов)?

Вопрос, конечно, философский. Да, наверное, можно сделать нечто шустрее, чем memcmp(), для ваших конкретных условий.
Как видится, основные предпосылки для создания альтернативы к memcmp():

Блоки памяти далеки от равновероятных. Поскольку для равновероятных блоков памяти в 99,6% случаев *s1 != *s2, и встроенный memcmp() для этого оптимизирован. А обгонять его в 0,4% случаев не очень осмысленно;

Блоки памяти выровнены особым образом. Скорее всего, компилятор, либо создаёт код memcmp() на месте, либо использует библиотечный вариант, соответствующий целевому набору команд, но у него могут быть сложности с определением выравнивания. И здесь его можно немного обогнать.

Блоки памяти имеют особую длину. Аналогично п. 2;

Какие-либо известные факты в деле кэширования блоков памяти.


К примеру, ваша my_memeq_256() должна оказаться эффективнее стандартной memcmp(), либо в случае п. 1, либо в случае п. 4, когда конец одной или обеих строк уже находится в кэш (вроде бы ваши тесты похожи на этот случай).
Что же касается того, что "Эта дополнительная функциональность может вызывать ненужные накладные расходы", то, во-первых, см. п. 1, и во-вторых, в случае длинных, почти совпадающих блоков памяти, memcmp() память ориентированная функция, так что пару дополнительных команд никто не заметит.
